# How to detect and read phone number from user sms message

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, sms

I'm building an application that read phone number from user sms message, i'm not talking about the sender phone number but a number inside the message.

Check the example message below;

"Y'ello!, your transfer of 1GB to 2348062570000 was successful and your new balance is 3072.0MB"

I'm interested in the number 2348062570000, this is similar to how Whatsapp identify calling number from user chat, any library or string manipulation that could solve the problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for any phone number, or that specific format?  If you're ok with it working for that but failing for XXX-XXXX or other formats, its fairly easy- just use a regex to find the right number of digits in a row.  If you're looking for any phone number, its much more difficult.

Comment: The phone number and the message are constant in that format, regrex will include the number "3072.0" which is not part of the phone number. @GabeSechan

Comment: A regex for any number would.  A regex for a certain number of digits would not.  Nor would a regex that didn't allow a '.' in the number.

Comment: Can you give example @GabeSechan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will extract all the 13 digit numbers out of a string and put them in an ArrayList:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPhones(String s) {
    String regex = "[0-9]{13}";

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        array.add(s.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
    }

    return array;
}
```

You can print the numbers:

```
    String s = "Y'ello!, your transfer of 1GB to 2348062570000 was successful and your new balance is 3072.0MB";
    ArrayList<String> array = getPhones(s);
    for (String phone : array) {
        System.out.println(phone);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the format of String and it never changes apart from the numbers, you can do something like this.

```
    String str = "Y'ello!, your transfer of 1GB to 2348062570000 was 
    successful and your new balance is 3072.0MB" +;

    String[] split = str.split(" ");
    String stringPrecedingPhoneNumber = "to";
    int index = IntStream.range(0, split.length)
            .filter(i -> stringPrecedingPhoneNumber.equals(split[i]))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(-1);
    System.out.print(split[index +1]);
```